# Give 'rwx' permission to the directory but don't want user to give mkdir and touch permission

Tags: permissions

I have created a directory named `demo` and gave read, write and execute to a user named `demoUser`.

What I want is the user to be able to read, write and execute the files of the `demo` directory, but not be able to delete any of the files. Is that possible?

I tried a technique in which I created 3 Groups: `reader`, `editor` and `admin`. I gave read permission to the `reader` group and edit permission to the `editor` group using:

```
setfacl OPTION X:NAME:Y /DIRECTORY
```

Now I added `demoUser` to the `editor` group. The user can read, write and execute files, but they can also delete files.

Is there any way in which `demoUser` would not able to delete files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sticky bit is a permission bit that is set on a file or a directory that lets **only the user/owner** of the file/directory or the root user delete or rename the file, **even when write permissions are given through group ownership**.

Sticky bit can be set with:

```
chmod +t /directoryname
```

After this, users with write permission should not be able to delete files inside that folder **unless they created the file/folder themselves**. You can also make all files in that folder inherit group ownership, by using:

```
chmod g+s /directoryname
```

I just did a little test to make sure. I created a folder named `testfolder`, with ownership `root:user1`. I set `775` permissions (`rwxrwxrw`) and then ran:

```
sudo chmod +t testfolder
```

to give it sticky bit, and:

```
sudo chmod g+s testfolder
```

to make new files inherit group ownership.

After that, I logged in with `user2`, which is group member of `user1`. I went inside the folder and tried to delete the `testfile` that had `rwx` permissions for group `user1`. Since `user2` is a member of that group, they should have permissions to delete it, but they didn't. Permission denied.

After that, I decided to remove the sticky bit, using:

```
sudo chmod -t testfolder
```

and then tried to delete the file again. It worked.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for since you don't want users to use `touch` or `mkdir`. This would only disallow them deleting stuff while keeping write.